# Does event object / argument get passed automatically to React event handlers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

The answer is probably, yes. Because it works, and we use it all day, I know. I am asking to be %100 sure and for future learners of React. I couldn't see it in the official docs of React, except giving [an example for passing multiple arguments to event handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) alongside the event object. So for example: As you can see `onFormSubmit`, although not having an `event` argument inside the JSX reference, it has access to the event object to do stuff (preventing page refresh on this example) at the execution.

If you write the `onFormSubmit` as an inline arrow function like `onChange` handler, you need to pass the event object, then it is not automatic.

```js
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { term:''}
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state.term) 
    }
 
     render() {
         return (
            <div className="ui segment" >
             <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form" >
                <div className="field" >
                    <label>Search</label>
                    <input type="text" 
                    value = {this.state.term} 
                    onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })} />
                    </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
         )
     }
 }

 export default SearchBar
```

Comment: This is not a React specific thing. For instance you can do `window.onload = myFunction;` and your function will then get called by the browser with the event as the first argument. If you use something like `onSubmit={e => this.onFormSubmit(e)}` you are creating an anonymous function that also gets called with the event as first argument, which then in turn calls your own handler and passes it along. So if React didn't do that for some reason, using `{e => this.onFormSubmit(e)}` wouldn't force it to; `e` would simply be undefined in that case.

Comment: Event handler functions are passed an `Event` object  but in case of React, event handlers are passed an instance of [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) which is just a cross-browser wrapper around the `Event` object

Comment: In other words: `you need to pass the event object, then it is not automatic` is wrong, because if it weren't still automatic, you wouldn't have anything to pass in the first place. And if you use `onSubmit={e => this.onSubmitForm()}` you're deliberately discarding the event. The fact that React passes the event and the fact that you have to pass it along if you state an anonymous function are two separate concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the function to your `onChange` event handlers which calls the submit method passing the necessary arguments implicity.

There is nothing special about `event` handlers in React. Every function, if defined works this way.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];

function print(elem, idx) {
    console.log(elem, idx);
}

// here you have defined the print function.
// the elem and idx are passed implicitly to run the function.
a.forEach(print);

or 

// now, rather than defining the function here.
// you have used another arrow function.
// then you need to pass the arguments explicitly.
a.forEach((elem, idx) => print(elem, idx));
```

Answer (score 2):

React approaches the event handling a little bit differently, using Synthetic Events but this is how callback handlers work generally. If you use a function reference there, the `event` object is the only argument passed to your function. So, if the event object is the only argument you want to get then you don't need to use an arrow function.

If you want to pass other variables alongside with the `event` object, then you can use an arrow function.

`<form onSubmit={e => this.onFormSubmit(e, otherVar)} className="ui form" >`

So, your callback gets the event parameter and you pass this to your handler function with your other variables.

```
onFormSubmit(event, otherVar) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(otherVar) 
}
```