# Magic event object passed to event handlers even if not defined

Tags: reactjs

I was helping a co-worker, and she had code that was -- boiled down -- essentially doing something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => console.log(event)}>Click Me</button>
```

Note that it was an anonymous function that was NOT passing in an `event` object but trying to access it anyway inside the body of the function (unlike [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066601/does-event-object-argument-get-passed-automatically-to-react-event-handlers)).

I was like, "yeah that's not going to work."

She was like, "no, pretty sure it does because it's been working."

Skeptical, I fired it up and tried it out. Sure enough, an event object is logged to the console. Also of interest is it's a native event object and not a React Synthetic Event.

What is this black magic sorcery?

Also curious if anyone can confirm. Otherwise maybe it's something specific to our setup (e.g. a fluke of our tooling). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I just figured out that the window object has a (deprecated) `event` property while in the context of the handler, and I believe that is what I am seeing.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event